# Change Microsoft Azure Portal Login ID

Tags: azure

I want to change my microsoft azure portal login id and the login email id is not the microsoft account, it's our company's emailid sales@regaloutsource.com. But when I try to login into account.microsoft.com using sales@regaloutsource.com to change the login id it says the microsoft account doesn't exist

Comment: Is this an Office 365 account?

Comment: Yes, and purchased on Godaddy.

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do here? Change the email address (say from sales@regaloutsource.com) to sales1@regaloutsource.com) or change the email address that accesses the Azure Portal?